# Windows 7 lost it's sounds after power shortage

Tags: windows-7, audio

I had my PC on and after a power shortage, Windows 7 lost all it's sounds.
The speakers work fine, I can play music, movies, games and everything, it's just the Windows sounds that are out for some reason (folder clicking, logging in/out, clicks, etc).

If I go to Personalize -> Change Sounds, no sound is played if I click on **any** sound there, no matter the theme.

The speakers on Windows configuration are working fine (they pass the test and such).

I tried troubleshooting already, nothing found.

I had this happen once a very long time ago, but I don't remember the solution (if there was one). Other than uninstalling, what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the speaker icon at the bottom-right of the screen? Click on that once and the volume level should be shown with "Mixer" at the bottom. Click on "Mixer" and adjust the "System Sounds" slider (or maybe just unmute it, if there is a red no-entry sign under that slider).

Comment: Ooohhh this was easier than I thought! Thank you very much!